# What is real usage of Loaders in android

Tags: android, multithreading

I have read about loader but can anybody explain what is the real use of a loader and why it uses or any real case scenario where loader should be used instead of other multithreading solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loaders should not be used anymore. It has been deprecated as of Android P (API 28).
From the official docs:

> Loaders have been deprecated as of Android P (API 28). The recommended
> option for dealing with loading data while handling the Activity and
> Fragment lifecycles is to use a combination of ViewModels and
> LiveData.

But on the Android developers site you can still find a [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders) with samples, where it was used.